# IIS7 SSL Cert replaced, still sending old expired cert to browser

Tags: iis-7, ssl

Previously I had a SSL Cert from another company. It expired last night. I purchased a new one this morning, deleted the first one from the server under "Server Certificates" and created a new request. When I clicked "Complete Certificate Request" and put in the new certificate - no problem, it installed.

However, in the browser, whenever I go to the site, I still get prompts in the browser saying that it's not secure. In Firefox, in the dialog that pops up to verify the certificate, I clicked "Get Certificate" a couple of times - it still said invalid, and when I clicked on View Details, the issuer name is that of the original cert, that is expired and deleted.

Only thing I could think of doing was restarting the server. No dice.

Any words of advice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you bind the new SSL Cert to the website? After you've completed a certificate request, you need to go to Sites > Website > in the Action Pane you'll see "Bindings" and make sure to bind the new cert to https:// (aka SSL).

Here's a handy dandy guide: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-windows-server-2008-iis-7.0.html (CTRL F + "Bind the Certificate to a website")

Comment: Good call. That was too easy.

Comment: I did that with no success.

Comment: Jeremy - Delete your old certs, edit the bindings, and make sure you restart IIS.

Comment: In my case it did not work either. After looking for a while, I've noticed that I had one site, where was certificate "not selected", which happed after switching to new cert. After manualy selecting the new cert and restarting iis, server started to send the new cert on all sites.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 years, the answer of "Catch" saved my life. After reading millions of forums, my problem was that one web site did not take the new cert automatically. After binnding it manually, everything worked.

"Catch", God bless you!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/529329)